# I need a drop down list to display a list of active cases, but I keep getting an error when there is more than one returned

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, nullreferenceexception

I need a drop down list to display a current set of active cases, but I get an error whenever it returns with more than one case. The code looks like this:

```
masterCaseList.DataSource = MasterCasesBLL.GetAllMasterCases(false)
    .Where(x => x.MainContact.MainContact == true)
    .Select(x => new { MainContact = x.MainContact.MainContactLabel, index = x.ID })
    .ToList();

masterCaseList.DataValueField = "index";
masterCaseList.DataTextField = "MainContact";
masterCaseList.DataBind();
```

And the error I get is:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. at PCM_UI.manageReferrals.b__2(CaseDTO x) in
>   c:\Users\Public\Documents\PathFinder Case
>   Manager\PCM.UI\pages\manageReferrals.aspx.cs:line 33 at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext() at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at
>   PCM_UI.manageReferrals.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\Users\Public\Documents\PathFinder Case
>   Manager\PCM.UI\pages\manageReferrals.aspx.cs:line 33

Comment: Can `x.MainContact` be null?  If so, `x.MainContact.MainContact` will error.

Comment: It shouldn't have been able to return a null value, but for some reason I guess it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try add the following in your query:

```
masterCaseList.DataSource = MasterCasesBLL.GetAllMasterCases(false)
    .Where(x => x.MainContact != null && x.MainContact.MainContact == true)
    .Select(x => new { MainContact = x.MainContact.MainContactLabel, index = x.ID })
    .ToList();
```

It appears that you have a null reference when the ToList method force the iteration.

Comment: OMG! That worked! Thank you so very much! Now that I have a list of all the active cases, I can get on with things. I been stuck here for almost 10 hours, over the past couple days. Thanks again!

Comment: It's kind of strange that it came back with null values, though. There isn't any null data in the table its getting the information from. But, oh well, I'm not complaining now that it works. Thanks!

Comment: Is that the check mark by the side of what you posted?? This is my first time on here so I'm a newbie lol.

Comment: Yes it is, tnx... =)
You could try to bring in a separate query just the records with a null MainContact, without using the Select extension. It can be an issue on your GetAllMasterCases method.

Comment: I might just do that, just to see what it is pulling null data from a populated table. Possibly save myself a headache somewhere down the line. You are a life saver lol. Is there an 'add friend' button on here somewhere??

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't, but it would be a nice implement, LOL.
Probably will save you some time in future. But it's always more safe to check for null values.